# java.io.IOException in Android while connecting to MongoDB database

Tags: android, mongodb

In my Android application, I am getting `java.io.IOException` when I am making connection with my database. Please tell what is the problem?

**Code:**

```
public void connect_to_db() {
    try {
        URL requestUrl = new URL("url for MongoDB database");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) requestUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
        connection.connect();
    }
    catch(Exception exp) {
        Log.e("TAG","Exception",exp);
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
05-09 03:07:22.711 2962-2962/com.example.abc.project1 E/TAG: Exception
                                                            java.io.IOException
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:87)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:165)
at com.example.abc.project1.LocationDetector.connect_to_db(LocationDetector.java:85)
at com.example.abc.project1.LocationDetector.onLocationChanged(LocationDetector.java:37)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:257)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:186)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:202)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5410)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you have Internet permission?

Comment: yes I have @Evin1_

Comment: I don't know the issue but it's safer to go through a web service rather than connect directly, because someone could decompile your app and get your database connection information, and then do whatever they want to your database (or at least do anything your user permissions would allow).

Comment: You should use Postman or just a browser to test weather the server works properly. Then check the code after that.